# combine list of sas datasets by passing them as list

Tags: sas

I am trying to combine two sas data sets. How can I create a file_list and use it in set statement together with libname.&file_list instead of calling them individually as shown below.

```
 libname my_data 'path_to_folder';

%let file_list = sas_file1 sas_file2;

data my_data.all;
set my_data.sas_file1;
set my_data.sas_file2;
run;
```

I can also do something like this.

```
  %let file_list = my_data.sas_file1 my_data.sas_file2;
    
    data my_data.all;
    set &file_list;
    run;
```

But I want a separate list of datasets which I can use irrespective of libname.

Comment: Do your data sets share a common prefix like sas_file1 and sas_file2 ?

Comment: @draycut no it could be very different as sas_file1 table2 data5 etc

Comment: May I kindly ask why you are using multiple set statements? The only reason I would use those latter would be to combine files when the __merge__ statement fails due to its memory and disk space feature. Also, your files need to have a one-to-one match.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  If your datasets are not in WORK then you need to use fully qualified name.  Why would you want the list of member names disconnected from the libref they are a member of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%macro prefix_list(prefix, list);
  %do _nr = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list));
    &prefix.%scan(&list, &_nr)
  %end;
%mend;

%let file_list = sas_file1 sas_file2;

data my_data.all;
  set %prefix_list(my_data., &file_list);
run;
```